# Problem with 100% background-image wrapper disappearing when scrolling

Tags: css, background-image

I have http://www.mrfishermusic.com/

You'll notice that the main wrapper is 1042px (#main). Then I have #container surrounding that which is width 100%. I made it like this because the background image of the page is huge width wise.

The problem is if the browser is resized small horizontally... say like.. 700px wide (or way smaller, like on an iPhone), when you scroll to the right the header and footer both just disappear, although the #main wrapper remains intact.

I see some other people had this issue but I'm not a CSS ninja so I couldn't quite reproduce the solution onto my site - I apologize if this has been asked before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The container size of 100% is relative to the viewport and is not updated when you scroll/resize. You have several options:

- use javascript to handle viewport size changes
- set the header container minimal size in pixels
- set the background on body instead (because it's not limited to the viewport size) : `background-image: url(background.png); background-position: center top;`

Comment: Thank you skolima, that was a huge help.. Would you mind if I ask a few more quick questions?

1. What is that script usually called? I tried viewport resize script but didnt find much about it.

2. This is the method I went with. it worked great but what about if the background goes outside of the 1042? I already have a texture on the body thats very high resolution as it is, I can't combine them or the texture would be like 2mb, so background image on body is out of question. In other words, without resorting to JS, is there another method to resize a div 100% to the viewport?

thanks!

Comment: There's a very good description available here: http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/ (using pseudoelements).

Answer (score 5):

Setting a `min-width` on the `<body>` can solve this problem, also.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works! Very simple.. very useful! Thanks